# Laravel Eloquent Distinct

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

i have this table

```
int id
string title
string year // maybe i'll change this to int??
```

and i want to loop my data without using another table to create a relationship using Year.

i want an output like this

```
2018 
 - title1
 - title2
 - title3
```

i know select distinct and then i have to create another query by the data i collect on select distinct.my question is this possible in eloquent and how?
Thanks.

what ive tried so far

```
$albums = Albums::groupBy('year')->get()->toArray();
```

and what i get doing it

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "title" => "Title1"
    "year" => "2017"
    "created_at" => "2019-02-01 07:46:30"
    "updated_at" => "2019-02-01 07:46:30"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "Title1"
    "year" => "2018"
    "created_at" => "2019-02-01 07:08:59"
    "updated_at" => "2019-02-01 07:08:59"
  ]
]
```

what i have in my table is

```
title1 2017
title2 2017
title3 2017
title1 2018
title2 2018
title3 2018
```

**EDIT**
got it using this

```
$albums = Albums::all()->groupBy('year')->toArray();
```

with output like this

```
array:2 [▼
  2018 => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▶]
    1 => array:5 [▶]
    2 => array:5 [▶]
  ]
  2017 => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▶]
    1 => array:5 [▶]
    2 => array:5 [▶]
  ]
]
```

Now gonna think of way how to display those year. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i tried the groupby query, but im getting Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Comment: Show us that attempt!

Comment: i just edit my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use the merge method?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-merge

```
$albums = Albums::all(); 
$year = new Collection(); 
foreach ($albums as $item) 
{ $year=$year->merge($item); $year=$year->flatten()->unique('year'); }
```